# Android phonegap JSCallback Error: Request failed.:801?

Tags: android, cordova

I've problem with `Phonegap` for `Android` , when the application start i got error in `CatLog` :

```
03-29 17:06:27.325: I/Web Console(32072): JSCallback Error: Request failed.:801
```

I've tried to Googled it no luck at all , this is the full `CatLog` error

```
03-29 17:05:52.270: W/CursorWrapperInner(31489): Cursor finalized without prior close()
03-29 17:06:26.890: I/PhoneGapLog(32072): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
03-29 17:06:26.940: I/dalvikvm-heap(32072): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.436MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-29 17:06:26.990: I/webclipboard(32072): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42678a98
03-29 17:06:27.130: E/(32072): Device driver API match
03-29 17:06:27.130: E/(32072): Device driver API version: 23
03-29 17:06:27.130: E/(32072): User space API version: 23 
03-29 17:06:27.130: E/(32072): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013 
03-29 17:06:27.220: I/GATE(32072): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
03-29 17:06:27.270: E/Web Console(32072): Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined:14
03-29 17:06:27.300: E/SQLiteLog(32072): (14) cannot open file at line 32516 of [00bb9c9ce4]
03-29 17:06:27.300: E/SQLiteLog(32072): (14) os_unix.c:32516: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
03-29 17:06:27.325: E/Web Console(32072): XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:38060/5a7be5f1-cefa-402a-ab69-2ff3cc9914da. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.:1
03-29 17:06:27.325: I/Web Console(32072): JSCallback Error: Request failed.:801
```

This is the Html index :

```
<!-- Copyright (c) 2012 Mobile Developer Solutions -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>


  </head>

  <body onload="init();">
    <input type="button" value="tessssst" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: please paste your JS,.
Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined: 14 ??

Comment: I've no JS files the `phonegap-1.4.1.js` generated by `phonegap` by default

Comment: What is that init(); then ?\